# There is a limit to the net map directories on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, path

I mapped 2 directores (W: and R:) for two folders on diferent paths on my local net. Now Im trying to map one more path and the option to map the folder just disapeared.  Is this the limit? How can I add more if its not reached the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a limit, it is over 26, and you are not even close to it. You have another issue. See if you can get more info, and post back exactly what you mean by "the option to map the folder just disapeared", and where is did that. A screenshot would be helpful.

For more on going over 26 lettered drives:

http://ask-leo.com/26_drives_is_there_a_way_around_the_26_drive_limit_in_windows.html

Comment: My Windows Seven is in Portuguese, the option that im talking about is when you right-click on some net folder(that I previousily opened with \\"ip addr") and one of the options is "Map this folder" or something like this. It dont appear any more....

Comment: Are you trying to map from within a drive that has already been mapped? In other words, are you opening your W: or R: drive, right-clicking a folder, and then trying? If so, that will not work. You also cannot do that after you open \\server\c$ (or whatever). You need to go to browse to the actual share, or open Computer, and go to Tool>Map a drive, at which point, you can point a letter at the share and add any subdirectory, for example \\server\C$\temp. The answer is that you are probably trying to do it from a place they don't allow it, and that it is not broken.

Comment: Its another IP, diferent from the W: and R:

Comment: In other words, you are just trying to do it from the wrong place. Doesn't matter what IP.

Comment: Do any of the following: Computer>Tools>Map a drive; or do a "net use N: \\ipaddress\sharename.

Comment: With net use it works, I successfully mapped my new path, however, I think there is some problem with windows at this point. It should give me the option to do this as it does before, just right-clicking on the net folder allowing me to map as a new drive. However, thank you very much KContreau again :D